# Gradle : assembleDebug task failed, after Flutter upgrade

Tags: firebase, gradle, flutter, dart

I was developping my flutter app when I saw a message in the console : "*a new version of flutter is available*". So I upgraded my flutter (`flutter upgrade`). and when I relunched my app I get this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 6 Pro in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"cbe486eb-0534b8c4cb74","id":"1","progressId":null,"message":"Resolving dependencies..."}}]Resolving dependencies...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

There is no `registerResGeneratingTask` in my code.. It probably come from a library (maybe firebase/cloud_firestore). Could be related to AndroidX also.

I didn't found any solution on other topics or websites.

Any idea would be great !

Answer (score 0):

Just download the latest vision of android below sync you and spot the error, then click on it, sync will install and update the Gradle Build:

[image]